# Check if a cell value in a datagrid binded to an observable collection is empty or duplicated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I searched for a while but I can't figure out how to check if the "Name" column of my datagrid is empty or contains an existing value. If so, the row shouldn't be added to the collection.

This is the class :

```
public class DataVals : BaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    #region Properties
    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _Name = "";
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            this.PropertyChangedNotify("BindId");
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public float Min { get; set; } = 0;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public float Max { get; set; } = 0;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public float ALVal { get; set; } = 0;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public float WLVal { get; set; } = 0;

----
}
```

The observable collection :

```
public ObservableCollection<DataVals> ListeDataTable { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DataVals>();
```

The Datagrid is binded to the ListeDataTable :

```
DgDataTable.ItemsSource = ListeDataTable;
```

The image bellow shows the issue, I can add rows with empty names:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you want to remove the rows with the empty Name? If you have bound the collection then the values are already inside it ?=! or what exactly do you mean by: "If so, the row shouldn't be added to the collection."

Comment: I need to check the Name before adding the row to the datagrid,

Comment: I can filter the collection when I leave the window, but I need to inform users that the Name is empty or duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection view  and filter it with the following snippet:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( ListDataTable );
        view.Filter = item =>
        {
            var dataVal = item as DataVals;
            if( dataVal == null )
                return false;

            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty( dataVal.Name );
        };
```

The binding uses the default view anyways, so you don't need to do anything else :)

Comment: I didn't know CollectionViewSource object, but this is working fine, I can't add a row with an empty name now. Is there a way to inform the user that the Name cell is empty ? I also need to check is the name is not duplicated

Comment: I'd recommend to create a callback to react to changes of ListDataTable. There you can write something like var duplicateNames = ListDataTable.GroupBy( i => i.Name ).Where( g => g.Count() > 1 ).Select( g => g.Key ); to find all duplicates, and filter them in the filter function.